# PHP + OBJ-C POST method return null

Tags: php, objective-c, post

I have a problem with $_POST method. I send  it by OBJ-C using this code:

```
NSString *postRegistration = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",usernameLog, passwordLog];
NSData *postData = [postRegistration dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myurl"]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

and try to use it in PHP

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
       $array = array($username);
       echo json_encode($array);
```

And i get null all time. I checked and with json everything is okay. So something must be wrong with POST method.

Comment: What does `print_r($_POST);` show?

Comment: It is loading but then gets again NULL